# Parse Server on Openstack with multiple User accounts (alternative to back4app, Heroku)

Tags: parse-platform, openstack

I'm a student and at college we're trying to setup our own backend service for our applications, as Backend like Firebase would cost us more.

We settled up on using Openstack to combine and manage the compute resources of multiple computers together in our college Lab, but now we want to make a web portal where our students can login and use the parse server dashboard.

How to setup multiple parse instances for each user and what containers to use and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with docker compose. You would need to write a `docker-compose.yml` file like this:

```
version: '2'

services:
  mongo-db:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
  parse-server1-user1:
    image: parseplatform/parse-server
    links:
      - mongo-db
    environment:
      - PARSE_SERVER_APPLICATION_ID=parse1-user1
      - PARSE_SERVER_MASTER_KEY=SOME_SECRET_MASTER1_USER1
      - PARSE_SERVER_DATABASE_URI=mongodb://mongo-db:27017/parse1-user1
    ports:
      - 1337:1337
  parse-server2-user1:
    image: parseplatform/parse-server
    links:
      - mongo-db
    environment:
      - PARSE_SERVER_APPLICATION_ID=parse2-user1
      - PARSE_SERVER_MASTER_KEY=SOME_SECRET_MASTER2_USER1
      - PARSE_SERVER_DATABASE_URI=mongodb://mongo-db:27017/parse2-user1
    ports:
      - 1338:1337
  parse-server1-user2:
    image: parseplatform/parse-server
    links:
      - mongo-db
    environment:
      - PARSE_SERVER_APPLICATION_ID=parse1-user2
      - PARSE_SERVER_MASTER_KEY=SOME_SECRET_MASTER1_USER2
      - PARSE_SERVER_DATABASE_URI=mongodb://mongo-db:27017/parse1-user2
    ports:
      - 1339:1337
  parse-server2-user2:
    image: parseplatform/parse-server
    links:
      - mongo-db
    environment:
      - PARSE_SERVER_APPLICATION_ID=parse2-user2
      - PARSE_SERVER_MASTER_KEY=SOME_SECRET_MASTER2_USER2
      - PARSE_SERVER_DATABASE_URI=mongodb://mongo-db:27017/parse2-user2
    ports:
      - 1340:1337
  parse-dashboard:
    image: parseplatform/parse-dashboard
    links:
      - parse-server1-user1
      - parse-server2-user1
      - parse-server1-user2
      - parse-server2-user2
    depends_on:
      - parse-server1-user1
      - parse-server2-user1
      - parse-server1-user2
      - parse-server2-user2
    environment:
      - PARSE_DASHBOARD_CONFIG={"apps":[{"appId":"parse1-user1","serverURL":"http://localhost:1337/parse","masterKey":"SOME_SECRET_MASTER1_USER1","appName":"parse1-user1"},{"appId":"parse2-user1","serverURL":"http://localhost:1338/parse","masterKey":"SOME_SECRET_MASTER2_USER1","appName":"parse2-user1"},{"appId":"parse1-user2","serverURL":"http://localhost:1339/parse","masterKey":"SOME_SECRET_MASTER1_USER2","appName":"parse1-user2"},{"appId":"parse2-user2","serverURL":"http://localhost:1340/parse","masterKey":"SOME_SECRET_MASTER2_USER2","appName":"parse2-user2"}],"users":[{"user":"user1","pass":"secret-pass1","apps":[{"appId":"parse1-user1"},{"appId":"parse2-user1"}]},{"user":"user2","pass":"secret-pass2","apps":[{"appId":"parse1-user2"},{"appId":"parse2-user2"}]}]}
      - PARSE_DASHBOARD_ALLOW_INSECURE_HTTP=1
    ports:
      - 4040:4040
```

Then run:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Comment: but this usually come as a hardcoding method,but our students expect a dashboard where they can login and just create a new project with a project name and it automatically generates an app ID and a Secret Key with other necessary configurations so that they can just use the parse SDK with the app to communicate, they expect a package like firebase, also need DNS support, how to make API call for client devices that reach the Parse Instance using the automatically generated app ID and master key and other credentials through network, we have a domain to forward to the openstack systems.

Comment: There is not an easy way to do this. You'd need to customize the Parse Dashboard and create your own mechanisms to change the configuration files that I sent you as  an example and launch new containers for each new app that is created.